# Type Native Wifi.Wlan + WlanReasonCode cannot be marshaled error

Tags: c#, marshalling, wifi

Wanted to ask your opinion on this error that I am getting while running my Wifi profile add code.

Now the code that you are seeing is an example which I am using (coz I am new to the Wlan interface in C#).

I am trying to add wlan capability to my program that will search for a certain wireless network, add that profile to the PC and connect it (ping test - got this working yay).

Please see the pic for the error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gAYv.jpg)
What I have found is that if I remove the Cheesecake profile from the windows folder, the error does not happen. This tells me that the error could be something due to the profile being stored already. But not sure about it.

I am attaching my example code here as well FYI. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using NativeWifi;

    namespace WIFI_CONTROL_EXAMPLE
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstNetworks.Items.Clear();
        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach(WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces )
        {
            Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[]networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
            foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
            {
                Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = network.dot11Ssid;
                string networkName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(networkName);
                item.SubItems.Add(network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(network.wlanSignalQuality + "%");
                lstNetworks.Items.Add(item);

            }


        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
        {

            string profileName = "Cheesecake"; // this is also the SSID
            string mac = "52544131303235572D454137443638";
            string key = "hello";
            string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>networkKey</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey><keyIndex>0</keyIndex></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName, mac, key);
            wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
            wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
        }



        //string x = "";

        //x = lstNetworks.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        //foreach
        //MessageBox.Show("you have selected " + x);
        //string profileName = x;
        //string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><name>{0}</name></SSID><nonBroadcast>false</nonBroadcast></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><connectionMode>manual</connectionMode><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName);
        //wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
        //wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);

    }
}
   }
```

thanks,
Mat

Comment: Could you run it under the debugger (or hit break) and get the actual line that is causing the problem? The fix you posted below seems confusing because while you are correct that Success is 0, Marshal.SizeOf(...) should return the size of the enum, which is probably 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have fixed the problem, but Im not sure what will be the effects of it.

I am using Managed Wifi API and within the WlanAPI.cs, there is a line of code that checks for the size of the return code. This is the line:

```
 int expectedSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Wlan.WlanReasonCode));
```

what I did find out was that when the Reason code is "Success", it has an enumerated value of 0. So I commented the line and added zero in the next line as such:

```
                            //int expectedSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Wlan.WlanReasonCode));
                            //if (notifyData.dataSize >= expectedSize)
                            //{
                            //    Wlan.WlanReasonCode reasonCode = (Wlan.WlanReasonCode) Marshal.ReadInt32(notifyData.dataPtr);
                            //    if (wlanIface != null)
                            //        wlanIface.OnWlanReason(notifyData, reasonCode);
                            //}
```

to

```
//int expectedSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Wlan.WlanReasonCode));
                            if (notifyData.dataSize >= 0)
                            {
                                Wlan.WlanReasonCode reasonCode = (Wlan.WlanReasonCode)Marshal.ReadInt32(notifyData.dataPtr);
                                if (wlanIface != null)
                                    wlanIface.OnWlanReason(notifyData, reasonCode);
                            }
```

this seems to work, but Im not sure if I opened a can of worms. 
Can you guys think of any other better solution?

Thanks,
Mat

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I think I'm having the same issue and not sure what to do right now.

Comment: Hey man yea I did as I mentioned it in the previous post... I did that and left it like that . Didn't mess with it after the change

Comment: See SimpleWifi: https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi/blob/master/SimpleWifi/Win32/WlanApi.cs#L131